# How to change .kl file without root

Tags: android-10, miui-12

I am using Xiaomi phone(redmi note 7, miui 12, mobile says it has full OTG support) and I would like to use games with my Xbox 360 wired controller. When I plugged it in, the light just flashed, and the phone didn't react to any buttons. (I tried to use otg troubleshooter, it says it's plugged in, it just don't work). I saw some answer to this question: use 1Controller (series of .kl files). I got it, and I have no idea how to use it, or write it in system/keylayouts without root. So, have anyone answer to:

1. How to safely and rather temporarily root my phone?
2. How to write to system without root?
3. How to use .kl files without writing it to system?
4. How to solve this controller issue?